# When passing state in next.js typescript I keep getting: is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to pass state in my react next.js typescript application from the index.tsx page to my signup component however I keep getting the error on the email useState hook:

Type '{ email: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
Property 'email' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.

How would I go about fixing this, my code is below

```
export default function Home() {
  // state to handle signup email and password
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <title>
        example
      </title>
      <div className={styles.container}>
      </div>
      <Signup email={email} /> //The error shows up here as I am passing the state
      <Login />
      <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It means that your `Signup` component does not take (or at least, is not declared to take) an `email` property. To tell whether the invocation or the declaration is wrong, you'll need to show us both.

Comment: and i feel incredibly stupid rn but thanks I didn't realize I wasn't passing it as props, it fixed the issue <3